# Spring + Thymeleaf: ResourceManager : unable to find resource 'index.vm' in any resource loader

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am using Spring Boot + Thymeleaf. I don't understand why I am getting this error on each request:
`ResourceManager : unable to find resource 'xxxx.vm' in any resource loader.` where xxxx is a view name.
Setting this in application.properties won't help:
`spring.velocity.checkTemplateLocation=false`

Answer (score 0):

Setting this in the configuration class will help:
`@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,VelocityAutoConfiguration.class })`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem setting in the applications.properties:

```
spring.velocity.enabled=false
```